# In Highcharts, the X-Axis label value is not binded completely when tried to update X-Axis with different label values

Tags: javascript, highcharts

["redirect to code"](http://jsfiddle.net/4j8dh16z/1/)

I have reproduced the issue in the above link.

The issue is as follows:

I want to update the X-Axis label values at my desired position and I am successfully able to update in the plot. But when I console the X-Axis value for particular point when chart is loaded the X-Axis label value is not properly binded. Whereas, the Y-Axis value is properly displaying.
Any comments over it might really be appreciated.

I am using `this.series[0].xAxis.update` to update the X-Axis label values

Thank you.

I have refrred ["Highcharts Library Link"](https://www.highcharts.com/)

Comment: Hi @mukhtar alam, Could you explain your problem more precisely? Everything seems to be working fine in your chart.

Comment: @ppotaczek the issue is when I had consoled the X-axis value in the load function, the index is being output but not the X-axis value. To be more precise, the points array of the series class has X-axis indexes. Like series[0].points[0].x is giving 0 and series[0].points[1].x is giving 1

Comment: Do you mean that `this.series[0].points[3].x` should be `0` instead of `3`? If so, please use `this.series[0].points[3].category`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fpbk3Lw6/